# Android - How to change xml views / layout with button click?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I want to use a button to change xml layout / view (what exactly do you call the page shown). I have developed a app that will feature many pages about 5 or 6, I need to be able to move forward with a button to a page and go back to the previous page with a different button.

button 1 is the forward button

button 2 is the backwards button

button 3 is a reset button (brings back to the first page)

Thank in advanced!

Comment: You can use FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: What exactly did **you tried** and failed before posting the question?

Comment: I am new to android development so i didnt fail at anything. I just knew that if i tried i would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make activities for each view or you could implement flipviewer

sample layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button android:id="@+id/flip_me"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Flip Me!"
/>
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
android:text="This is the first panel"
/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#FFFF0000"
android:text="This is the second panel"
/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF00"
android:text="This is the third panel"
/>
</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

sample activity:

```
public class FlipperSample extends Activity {

 ViewFlipper flipper;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        flipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.details);

        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.flip_me);

        btn.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) new flipMyView());

    }

 class flipMyView implements View.OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(View view) {
   flipper.showNext();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewFlippers or you can set the layout to your activity on button click...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setContentView(R.layout.newLayout)` to change the layout
On the buttons `onClick` call the `setContentView` with different layout file
like this

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.newLayout);
        }
    });
```

NOTE:Since your doing like this `findViewById(R.id.button1)` will create `NullPointerException` if that view does not have that element so be carefull